# This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-post, jsonresult

I want to take both 'Blog Entry' and 'Blog Entry Photo' from controller with ajax. When taking only 'BlogEntry' there isnt any problem ,on the other hand, when taking both of them (BlogEntry and BlogEntryPhoto), there is a problem: **"This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."**

I think the problem is in 'Blog Entry Photo' because it has photopath column like "/Content/img/blog/25052017_2334_400x400.jpg". 
I used JsonResult but it doesnt work

```
return Json(new { Success = true, BlogEntries = blogEntries, BlogEntryPhotos = blogEntryPhotos}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

what should i do?

Comment: At VS, thanks to breakpoints I checked whether data is taken by client but  data is taken. I think the problem is PhotoPath becuse of MIMETYPE at AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i eventually solved this issue arising from PhotoPath data. First, at controller, data of both BlogEntry and BlogEntryPhotos are serailized together then at view this data is parsed as object.

CONTROLLER

```
List<BlogEntry> blogEntries = _blogEntryRepo.GetAll(x => x.IsActive.Value && x.PlaceMarkerID == placeMarker.Id, null, "BlogEntryPhotoes").ToList();
JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
return Json(new { Success = true, BlogEntries = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blogEntries, Formatting.Indented, jss) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

VIEW

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/Map/GetBlogEntries",
      type: "post",
      datatype: "json",
      data: placeMarker,
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.Success) { 
             var BlogEntries = JSON.parse( response.BlogEntries );
             //BlogEntries[i].Title can be used
             //BlogEntries[i].BlogEntryPhotoes[0].PhotoPath can be used
        }
        else {
                //do something
    }
      },
      error: function (xhr, status) {
        //do something
      }
});
```